# Best way to setup a try/catch in a click listen case?

Tags: android, android-intent, try-catch

I have a case that opens a PDF by going to the sd card and looking for a file, and then opening it. The only things I can think of that would force it throw an exception would be if it couldn't find the file, or the user does not has adobe reader. If they file doesn't exist, adobe reader already displays a dialog and returns to the app, but I would like to catch it before that happens.

```
    case R.id.ImageButton2:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent();                 
        intent2.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");    
        intent2.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/afipresents/brochures/MultiLineBrochure.pdf")), "application/pdf");  
        startActivity(intent2); 
        break;
```

Comment: Your code for the `try-catch` should go within the com.adobe.reader source file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try{
// ur code
} catch (Exception e) { // or u can have specific exceptions
        showDialog(title_error,R.drawable.error_icon,msg_error_,label_ok);
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```